# Microsoft Chart draw coordinates of point

Tags: visual-c++, mschart

I am using  MS Chart Control to draw simple 2D chart. 
I would like that each point have label which contain his own coordinates, i.e: `2,5` (where 2 is X, and 5 is Y).

I found that in Series property is something like IsValueShownAsLabel, but it shows only Y value of point.

My question is: what is the simplest way to reach that?

Comment: Write an event handler for the PostPaint event to draw anything you want on top of the chart.

Comment: Try setting the `Label` as `#VALX,#VALY`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i found an answer.

```
chart1->Series["Series1"]->Label = "(#VALX;#VAL)";
```

or in Properties of chart -> Series -> Label and here type: (#VALX; #VAL)